# Android process should not pause when screen is locked

Tags: android

I have one process running in android device the problem is  process is going to pause state when i lock the screen and resumes from the same point when I unlock the screen, I want that process to run continuously even if device screen is locked(i.e when screen is off)... Please suggest me the best possible solution..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: put the process in a service. however, this service might be killed once the device is low on memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Comment: One more issue... When app is running if I come to desktop(home screen) it is getting pause state again.. The issue with screen lock is solved but same same issue occuring when i minimise the app or come to home screen.. In fact the home screen also an activity right? so I want it to run no matter which activity comes in front.. Do u have any Idea..?

Comment: In that case you will not need a wake lock, but a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is caleld service ( some piece of code running independet of UI ) . When screen is locked, whatever activity is in focus receives onPause() callback  and is stopped.

You will have consider battery consumption issue.  Just answer yourself questions

- does your service really have to run permanently in background?
- can work be done with irregular callbacks?

Consider to implement  it as broadcast receiver weacked up by  periodic alarms

Comment: Indeed it depends whether they want the process to run always or only if it's in the foreground (with the screen locked). If it has to run always => use a service, otherwise => use a wake lock.